# IE8 repeat-y fails

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm setting a background for a div like that:

`background:transparent url(images/con-left-bg.PNG) repeat-y;`

however it's filling whole space instead repeating it vertically only...

Is there a way to fix that so it'll work for IE8?

Comment: It should work. Can you provide a demo for us to test?

Comment: 'my' IE8 does support repeat-y... http://jsfiddle.net/YBwvT/1/

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `repeat-x`?

Comment: is your file extension .png or .PNG? Or are you maybe overriding your rule somewhere else in your css. Otherwise works ok in all IE browsers including IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating out your CSS into separate `property:value;` pairs, and put quotes around the url.

```
background-image: url('images/con-left-bg.PNG');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-color: transparent;
```

But be aware that setting the background-color to transparent sometimes gets wonky in IE.

Comment: The first two should not matter.

Answer (score -1):

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

you forgot that part :P , and another thing. end every statement with a semicolon(;)

Comment: @willem you mean "answers that should be comments are not answers" :P